# Toggle poles of DC using single port switch

Tags: batteries

[image]

I need to toggle the poles of a DC battery using a switch.
can you make such a circuit for me? please ...

Comment: DPDT \${}{}{}{}{}\$

Answer (score 3):

Use a double pole double throw switch (DPDT)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGwXp3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> I need to toggle the poles of a DC battery using a switch

Your push button switch is likely to have switch bounce so a debounce circuit will be needed but, the basic toggling can be done with a D type flip-flop. Each time you press and releae the switch the D type flip flop changes its output from low to high and back again.

[image]

The clock input comes from your push button debounce circuit. Here's a chip that can work as a switch debouncer: -

[image]

Finally, use a DPDT relay driven from a transistor (probably NPN) and wire up the relay contact to reverse the battery direction. Relay driver: -

[image]

Relay reverser (for a motor but any load will be OK): -

[image]