# Turning a torch on or off using a single mini-switch

Tags: batteries, switches, toggle-switch

I need a circuit to turn on and off a torch, as given in the figure. The circuit must turn the output on when I press the mini-switch once, and turn the output off when I press the mini-switch again.

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a mini-switch? Why not use a slide switch or a different kind of button? This seems very similar to your previous question. What are you trying to make?

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141702/toggle-poles-of-dc-using-single-port-switch

Comment: T-FF with debounced input?

Comment: Use a latching switch.

Comment: Yes i need mini switch. I am a beginner now a days i am making my project by coupling different functioning circuit @AdamHaun Haun

Answer (score 1):

You need a J/K-Flipflop. Connect the J and K Input to VCC and the Clk-Input must be connected to VCC via switch.

[image: FlipFlop]

Pay attention to the input voltage and VCC of the IC. Not all can operate with 6 V, but some like the 74HC112.

Debounce with a cap.

Comment: It is effectively a T-Flipflop.

Comment: Clock line normally needs fast rise and fall times.  Debouncing with a RC network causes slow edges that won't work with most flip-flops.

Answer (score 1):

One low-cost solution is to make an alternate-action latching circuit.  The following circuit dates to many years ago but works well.  If physical size is an issue, the chip is available in a 5-pin or 6-pin SOT-23 package, as is a small MOSFET.

You mention that you want to run this from 6V.  The chip I'm going to suggest is an old-fashioned CD4049 but almost any inverter will work so long as it is rated for your supply voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSKEOm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit functions by using C1 as a short-term memory element.  It stores the state of the node between the two inverters.  When the switch is pressed, that level is opposite of the level at the input of inverter #1, so the inverter changes state to the opposite level.  The ratio of R1 & R2 is such that C1 can't charge back to the new level until the button is released.  C2 simply provides noise immunity.